# Find source of query through pgbouncer

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I am trying to figure out as much as I can about what host a particular type of update query is coming from.

My database is PostgreSQL 9.0.23 locally running pgbouncer for connection pooling.  The pooling type is transaction pooling.

A trigger in the database saving information from `pg_stat_activity` tells me about the pgbouncer connection, but doesn't help me figure out who is behind that.

The database in question is a production database under load.  Therefore removing pgbouncer is not an option.  Having pgbouncer write a verbose log is probably also a bad idea.

Is there any reasonable way to find out which host the query ultimately comes from?

Answer (score 1):

The way I use to keep tracking clients from pgbouncer is joining `pg_stat_statements` with pgbouncer `show clients` command. Here is an example:

```
t=# create extension "postgres_fdw";
CREATE EXTENSION
t=# CREATE SERVER pgbouncer FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS ( host '10.10.10.10', port '6432', dbname 'pgbouncer');
CREATE SERVER
```

(By all means you can use just dblink or just postgres_fdw - I use mix to support obsolete usage on prod... If you did not have any notes, just ignore that...)

```
t=# create extension "dblink";
CREATE EXTENSION
t=#  create view bnc_client AS SELECT _.type,
        _."user",
        _.database,
        _.state,
        _.addr,
        _.port,
        _.local_addr,
        _.local_port,
        _.connect_time,
        _.request_time,
        _.ptr,
        _.link,
        _.remote_pid,
        _.tls
       FROM dblink('pgbouncer'::text, 'show clients'::text) _(type text, "user" text, database text, state text, addr text, port integer, local_addr text, local_port integer, connect_time timestamp with time zone, request_time timestamp with time zone, ptr text, link text, remote_pid smallint, tls text);
CREATE VIEW
t=# create user mapping FOR vao server pgbouncer options (user 'pgbouncer_known_user', password 'password_here');
CREATE USER MAPPING
```

Now we can join pgbouncer view with `pg_stat_statements`:

```
t=# select
        datname
      , usename
      , p.state
      , case when b.user is not null then 'pgBouncer' else application_name end app
      , case when b.user is null then client_addr else addr::inet end ip
      , b.user
      , b.state "bState"
      , case when waiting then true else null end w
      , b.connect_time
      , query_start
      , md5(query)::uuid
      , pid
    from pg_stat_activity p
    left outer join bnc_client b
      on addr||':'||b.port = regexp_replace(p.application_name,'^.{0,}(- )','')
    where pid <> pg_backend_pid()
  ;
 datname | usename | state |          app           |      ip      | user | bState | w | connect_time |          query_start
|                 md5                  |  pid
---------+---------+-------+------------------------+--------------+------+--------+---+--------------+-------------------------------
+--------------------------------------+-------
 dbn  | usr   | idle  |                        | 192.168.0.1 |      |        |   |              | 2017-03-09 17:19:46.206643+00
| d1730c52-dffd-3650-a399-23f4dd4aa456 | 12614
 dbn  | usr   | idle  | app - 10.10.10.10:24514 | 10.10.10.10  |      |        |   |              | 2017-03-10 11:24:34.999174+00
| 92a0340c-9ecc-9375-37c0-e70e8b225db4 | 22563
(2 rows)
```

Here `app - 10.10.10.10:24514` means this pid is from pgbouncer, and to pgbouncer it connected from 0.10.10.10